# CustomControl with textField and label in swfit 4

Tags: ios, swift, custom-controls, textfield

I'm trying to create a `@IDesignable` custom control which contains `UITextField` and `UILabel`.
I created a subclass of `UIView` and `UITextFieldDelegate`. In this class in method `awakeFromNib()` I create `textField` and add it to the `View` with `addSubview()`. To my main `ViewController` on storyboard I add a View control and sets its class to my new class. But nothing happen. I don't see text field. This is my code:

```
@IBDesignable class CTextField: UIView, UITextFieldDelegate {
    var textField: UITextField?
    var label: UILabel?

    @IBInspectable var placeHolderText: String = "" {
        didSet {
           textField?.placeholder = placeHolderText
        }
     }

     override func awakeFromNib() {
          textField =  UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 100, width: 300, height: 40))
          textField?.placeholder = placeHolderText

          self.addSubview(textField!)
     }}
```

Where I should create a textField ? In which method on my class CTextField ? Should I override draw method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do next:

- In the view controller create `@IBOutlet weak var customTextFieldView: CTextField!`
- Connect `customTextFieldView` in the `storyboard`

[image]
 - Setup correct constraints for your view:

[image]

- Setup `placeHolderText` in storyboard

Finally update your class like this:

```
@IBInspectable var placeHolderText: String = "" {
        didSet {
            textField?.placeholder = placeHolderText
            updateView()
        }
    }
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

func updateView() {
    subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }

    textField =  UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 40))
    textField?.backgroundColor = .red
    textField?.placeholder = placeHolderText

    self.addSubview(textField!)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is not a solution of my problem. I want to see my custom control on storyboard with all containing controls. Code above creating a textField but I can see it only on runtime. TextField is place on the bottom of the view.

Comment: thanks for this! It works perfectly:) Another challenge is handle standard TextField methods Ediditg Did Begin/End and so on... ;)